# Inserting a New Sheet in a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

How can I insert a new blank sheet (a new tab) into an existing Google Spreadsheet?  I'm able to duplicate those that already exist on the bottom, but I can't find the menu option to insert a sheet.

This is the most basic thing to do in Excel, but none of the documentation seems to say a thing about doing it in Google Docs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The bottom of the window will list your tabs on the left and have a couple options to the left of those.  Clicking the `+` will add a new sheet.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also go to the **Insert** menu and choose **New Sheet**. That will add a new sheet directly to the right of the sheet that is currently active.